# Filling only one bootstrap row with background video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been wondering is it possible to only fill one specific row element with background video so that all other rows above and below would stay responsive.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">top element</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <video width="1920" height="1080" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
      <source src="background_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">bottom element</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div with `container-fixed` class and then use `col-xs-*` to force non-responsiveness:

```
<div class="container-fixed">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <video width="1920" height="1080" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
          <source src="background_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```